# Make <input> not editable except using <DateTimePicker> on React-Native-Elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

When the user clicks on an `< input >` element, I get a modal to be displayed for the user to select a DateTime. Then, the selected value is shown as a value for the `< input >` element. This is working fine.

**1st problem:** 
However, after that, a cursor is displayed in the `< input >` element. This is NOT good. If the user enters anything, it gets overridden, because it gets the state value, which was already set by the DateTime Picker. This element should NOT be editable manually. It should only accept values from the DateTime picker.

**2nd Problem:** 
If the user clicks again on the `< input >` element, the modal does NOT get displayed again. This is NOT good. I want the user to be able to select a different value.

How can I fix the above 2 problems?

```
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
.... 
state = {
    isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
};
..... 
<Input
    label='From'
    placeholder='01/01/2019 09:00 AM'
    onFocus={() => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true })}
    value={dateTimeValue}
/>
<DateTimePicker
   isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
   onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
   onCancel={this.hideDateTimePicker}
/>
.... 
handleDatePicked = (dateTime) => {
    this.hideDateTimePicker();
    this.setState({ shiftFromDateTime: dateTime });
};

hideDateTimePicker = () => {
  this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For the user to write you can just put `editable={false}`. This will also block your `onFocus` event, to solve it you would need to use a touchableOpacity around the `<Input>` that does the same action as onFocus so it would be:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true })}>
   <Input
   label='From'
   placeholder='01/01/2019 09:00 AM'
   editable={false}
   value={dateTimeValue}
   />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This should also resolve the second problem.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for your input. (1) You need to change the last character on the 1st line from } to  >. (2) No, it did not work. I got the following error message. Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Glad it helped! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

In my released app i've never had these kind of problems, i use https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

- no need to use an external `Input` component, because this `DatePicker` component has also the non-manually-editable input
- no need to use a state to know if the modal is opened or closed
- no problems on editing date more than 1 time
- it uses a more platform-specific approach (opening the modal on android and the datepicker actionsheet on ios)

Comment: This is a good component. Thanks for sharing. I wonder if it is possible for a "datetime mode" to show the date picker in a "calendar" format but the time picker in a "spinner" format.